# How to find memory leak using Memory Analyzer in android?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

i am trying to use Memory Analyzer tool in android. When i followed exactly as in one of their document, i got a graph like this.The blog is stopped there.Nothing said about memory leak.What should i infer from these graph?Can anyone tell me how to find memory leak from these graph or how these graphs are helpful in finding memory leaks.Any help in this regard is appreciable. I will provide some more details
     [image]

some description given by Memory Analyzer tool...

```
    One instance of "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk" loaded by "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" occupies 60,836,984 (57.41%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk" loaded by "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt".

    Keywords
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk
    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt

     Shortest Paths To the Accumulation Point

    Class Name  Shallow Heap    Retained Heap

    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk @ 0x911c130
    64  60,836,984

    sCurrentSdk class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk @ 0x207de4c0
    16  6,672

    [129] java.lang.Object[640] @ 0x9759008
    2,576   81,632

    elementData java.util.Vector @ 0x8d38170
    24  81,656

    classes org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader @ 0x8d0a570 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
    64  119,256

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController$6 @ 0x228b8630
    0   0

    <class> com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController$6 @ 0xc626c60 Thread
    120 25,664

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController$7 @ 0x228b8d48 »
    0   0

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController @ 0x225cdd70 »
    40  280

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainer @ 0x20807a68 »
    0   0

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.actions.AvdManagerAction @ 0x20b6cc78 »
    0   0

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.actions.SdkManagerAction @ 0x20b6e080 »
    0   0

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.actions.NewXmlFileAction @ 0x20b70728 »
    0   0

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.actions.NewTestProjectAction @ 0x20b713b8 »
    0   0

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.actions.NewProjectAction @ 0x20b71de0 »
    0   0

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.RunLintAction @ 0x20b774f8 »
    0   0

    <classloader> class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.manifest.ManifestEditor @ 0x21b9fb10
```

Comment: Serioulsy, you got to see this video. This guy explains the use of memory analyzer very clearly http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF0QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_CruQY55HOk&ei=Yl4iUNivMeaviQeOh4DoCw&usg=AFQjCNEfUDM7yYu-Cb6hrLjEOm5xk29LkA

Comment: Can you suggest some other tools?

Comment: No. This is the best as of now.